# unity-control-center uninstalled itself

Tags: unity, apt, aptitude

I don't know how it got uninstalled since I had it before, but when I try to install it again I get the following error:

```
oierlauzi@akerbeltz:~$ sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an 
   impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some   
   required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have read several answers but none have solved my issue. I also could not solve it by using aptitude.

Comment: try running "sudo apt-get -f install" and "sudo apt-get upgrade to resolve the dependancies, but also consider moving to a stable distro as that is mainly what the error is about, as it can't seem to find some of the packages required by some installed (or yet to be installed) packages.

Comment: Hi Oierlauzi, what version of Ubuntu do you have? Cual version de Ubuntu tienes amigo?

Comment: why was my answer converted to a comment?

Answer (score 1):

When I upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 I got a lot of depency errors like this one. It turns out during the update many of the software sources are deactivated and one needs to activate them again by going into the software center. Edit-> Software Sources -> Other Software
And check all the sources once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following first:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The last 2 lines are just to make sure the repositories and cache and error free.
Another way is:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
```

Another way is by actually installing the packages they are dependent on.

```
sudo apt-get install libcheese-gtk23 libcheese7
sudo apt-get -f install`
```